# Непонятная ошибка при установке пака pip плагинов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

пытался установить через requirements.txt, выдаёт странную ошибку при распаковке и установки. Буду рад советам по исправлению.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\михал\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\МИХАЛ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xvwf_5c6\\llvmlite_5bbdd40dcb7b406e95d0dbfae9000154\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\МИХАЛ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xvwf_5c6\\llvmlite_5bbdd40dcb7b406e95d0dbfae9000154\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\МИХАЛ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_zssx5fa\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\михал\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\llvmlite' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Версия python'a- 3.9[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки буквами.

Comment: Run pip install -r requirements.txt (Python 2), or pip3 install -r requirements.txt (Python 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку исправил, библиотека numba совместима только с python 3.7, пришлось откатить. Теперь все работает!

Answer (score 0):

Если раньше Вы использовали Python другой версии то просто скопируйте файлы оттуда. Если нет, попробуйте `pip install wheel`